# I want to add new items to top like twitter

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView and Im getting datas from api with Alamofire (I have PHP(Laravel) Backend). I made a timeline like twitter and when I`m using pull to refresh its reloading all datas but its not usefull because if someone pull to refresh they will scroll to top everytime.

I want they will stay current scroll position and new items will added to top and when they scrooling to top they will continue to read posts like twitter. I hope you will understand what I mean. I research it but I cant find any similar issue, i think its because I dont know how can I describe this.

API for review : https://gasome.com/api/post

Im using KafkaRefresh pod for pull to refresh

```
self.mCollectionView.bindHeadRefreshHandler({
self.id.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
self.loadPosts()
}, themeColor: UIColor.blue, refreshStyle: .native)
```

Comment: What is supposed to trigger the refresh if you don't want to pull-down to do it?

Comment: When users open the app Im calling pull to refresh func for reload it at willAppear

Comment: You said, "I want they will stay current scroll position and new items will added to top..." If they are staying at the current scroll position, what would cause the new items to be added?

Comment: If you`re using twitter its showing posts from your last scroll position when you open app again. Its loading newest content from your last position and showing you a button for "More Tweets". I wanna make same thing, I record a video for explain what I want :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dazsEVeVhwX90r0pVJvoAO4WOT6SqRgk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You want to use UICollectionView's `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` function. There are a few tutorials on how to use it and I suggest you use a diff algorithm like https://github.com/wokalski/Diff.swift too.

---

After reading your comments... This is a big ask. It is *not* a trivial thing to do. You will need to keep track of the content offset of the collection view every time the user scrolls and store it. Then whenever the user brings the screen to the foreground, you will have to download the newest data, add a value to the stored content offset for the number of points that the new data has added to the top of the screen and then set the collection views content offset to that value.

You likely won't find sample code to show you how to do this because it's the kind of thing that a company pays good money to have an experienced developer setup.

Comment: Thanks but I couldnt find any example for understand it :( Im newbie at swift, is there any tutorial about this ? Thanks for reply :)

Comment: There is not pagination at api atm but I can add it easly in a couple minutes, is it help me for solve this issue ?